# Highlight duplicates 2 columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

Is there a way to compare 2 columns and highlight those data if column A has a partial match with data in column B?

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXMATCH(B1, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A:A))
```

[image: 0]